# What is difference between lock and latch lock in connectors?

Tags: connector, header

What is difference between lock and latch lock in connectors? eg 87832-1420 is a mentioned as lock and DF51A-14DP-2DSA is mentioned a s latch lock

Links:

[87832-1420](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/part-detail/pcb_headers/0878321420#)
[DF51A-14DP-2DSA(01)](https://www.hirose.com/product/p/CL0543-5048-0-01)
Also [Detent Lock 620303124022](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/datasheet/620303124022.pdf)

Comment: Link For the mentioned components:
87832-1420 - https://www.molex.com/molex/products/part-detail/pcb_headers/0878321420#
DF51A-14DP-2DSA(01) - https://www.hirose.com/product/p/CL0543-5048-0-01
Also Detent Lock,
620303124022 - https://www.we-online.com/catalog/datasheet/620303124022.pdf

Comment: I don't think these terms have a standard universal meaning. You just need to read the datasheets to find out what they mean.

Comment: In this case "latch lock" means that you have to press the release mechanism on both sides to unplug it. But that term isn't used in the manufacturer's data sheet anywhere (they call it a "positive lock") so it's just what someone else somewhere has chosen to call it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for once thing, neither one is a lock. Lock is a mechanism that requires a key to release, and neither of these connector does. Indeed, very few connectors are truly locked: "powerlock" unipole connectors (a plastic key is needed to release before unmating) and some specialized circular connector for railway applications (they use a standard padlock).

To answer your question:

- The so-called "Detent lock" (or "passive-lock") is actually "detent fastening": the mates snap into place; to unmate, you need to pull a little bit harder to get past the snap (no other action is required)
- The co-called "latch-lock" (or "active-lock") is actually "latch fastening": the mates snap into place; to unmate, and you need to first release the latch (e.g., by pressing a lever) then pull. So, action *is* required.

**TL;DR**: the difference is that the latter requires user action before unmating.